# Bootstrap 3 slide in sidebar disconnects from menu when scroll?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a slide in navbar to my website but I have noticed that when I click on the "icon button" to open the nav that if scroll on the page the nav disconnects from the menu and scrolls with the content.  I am sorta new at bootstrap and I am not exactly sure what is causing this.

I have tried to change

```
.side-collapse-container {
                width:100%;
           -->     position:relative;             
                left:0;
                transition:left .4s;

            }
```

to

```
.side-collapse-container {
                width:100%;
          -->       position:fixed;            
                left:0;
                transition:left .4s;

            }
```

However the fixed causes a different issue. When the fixed is add I am now unable to scroll any of the content when the "icon button" has not been clicked. The content seems to be "locked"

[image]

Can someone please advise how I can correct this?

Sample is located here -- https://stevia-affirm.codio.io/DaveTest.html

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: You could try positioning the open nav on mobile with `absolute` and set it's container to `relative`, unless you want the navigation to specifically scroll when you move scroll up or down? It's unclear from the question as to what exactly you want or expect to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the navigation goes mobile in the media query, use this:

```
.side-collapse {
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    transition: width 0.4s ease 0s;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

because you have fixed-positioned navbar, it is sticking to the bottom, once it's position changes to absolute and top-height is changed, it works just fine.